# Wordpress Error establishing a database connection For Admin login only

Tags: wp-admin, front-end, wp-config

I am having this strange Error thing happening I can load the wp frontend fine but the wp/wp-login.php gives : `Error establishing a database connection`

Does the wp-config.php is for both frontend and backend?

This is a multisite by the way, I have 2 sites on it both loads the frontend just fine!

Any Ideas? thanks.

Comment: Both the frontend and backend use the same database settings from `wp-config.php`. This seems very strange, have you contacted your web host regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue but don't know why it was giving me the error establishing a database connection.

But it's fixed by changing entries in three tables what happened was that moved Wordpress to new server with different domain and there were instances of the old domain.

Thank you!